# Bash: replace the line before one pattern by other line that contains other pattern

Tags: bash

I am working with a compound database in sdf format. I would like to simple replace the head title of all molecules (with the pattern $$$$ before the title) by the line followed by > <GENERIC_NAME>.

The file looks like this:

```
$$$$
91443
  -OEChem-10051719083D

 55 57  0     1  0  0  0  0  0999 V2000
   -5.0661   -1.1129    2.4181 O   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    4.2383    1.9583    1.7563 O   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    7.3280    0.6119   -1.9919 O   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    5.1868    0.6987   -2.7387 O   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

> <GENERIC_NAME>
> Tetrahydrofolic acid

The script should replace 91443 by Tetrahydrofolic acid and do the same task in all lines with the head $$$$ and replace by the > <GENERIC_NAME> (there are about 9000 molecules, each one with different names and number codes).

This SDF file can be downloaded in the next web page (after registration, sorry): https://go.drugbank.com/releases/latest#structures

Thanks in advance for the replies, but those only change the first molecule, not the rest.
Best regards and thank you very much for your concern and help!!!

I tried in a simple way GREP both patterns and replace by sed with no result:

```
a=$(grep -A 1  --no-group-separator "$$$$" test.sdf | grep -v "$$$$")
b=$(grep -A 1  --no-group-separator "GENERIC_NAME" test.sdf | grep -v "GENERIC_NAME")
while $a $b,
do 
    sed -i "s/$a/$b/" test.sdf
done
```

Comment: please update the question to show the expected result; also review the current formatting of the input ... is `<GENERIC_NAME> Tetrahydrofolic acid` part of `test.sdf`? if 'yes' ... the current formatting in the question is confusing as to where the `<GENERIC_NAME>` entry resides in the file

Comment: The question is unclear, what I got is you want to `"replace 91443 by Tetrahydrofolic acid"` as remove `91443` which follows `$$$$` by `"Tetrahydrofolic acid"`?

Answer (score 1):

After correcting some syntax errors, the `grep`/`sed` combination will only work when you have exactly 1 match in a file. You want to replace all. You can use `awk` which is great for logic that spans different lines.
With the GNU `sed` option `-z` you can try some magic, but additional information would be fine.
When you are sure that you only have the `>` character in `<GENERIC_NAME>`, you can use

```
sed -rz 's/(\$\$\$\$\n)[^\n]*\n([^>]*)> ([^\n]*)/\1\3\n\2> \3/g' test.sdf
```

However, when you can have more `>` characters (or `<GENERIC_NAME>` is in fact a different string, you might need something like

```
sed -rz 's/<GENERIC_NAME>/\r/g;
  s/(\$\$\$\$\n)[^\n]*\n([^\r]*)\r ([^\n]*)/\1\3\n\2<GENERIC_NAME> \3/g' test.sdf
```

The `sed` commands gets uglier for each iteration (fix for another requirement) you implement, so it is a good idea to look at `awk`. Something like

```
awk -F'>' '
  /\$\$\$\$/ { getheader=1; print; next }
  getheader {header=$0; getheader=0; getbody=1; next}
  /<GENERIC_NAME>/ { printf("%s\n,%s\n%s\n", $2, body, $0); getbody=0; body=""; next}
  getbody { body = body $0 "\n"; next}
  {print}
  ' test.sdf
```

PS: Please edit your question (formatting, example output, show if there can be any lines outside the `$$$$`-`<GENERIC_NAME>` blocks)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, you want to `"replace 91443 by Tetrahydrofolic acid"`, meaning remove `91443` which follows `$$$$` and replace it with `"Tetrahydrofolic acid"`. If that is the case, then a simple `awk` expressions will do that simply sets a flag when `"$$$$"` is encountered as a line, replacing the next line with `"Tetrahydrofolic acid"`, meaning remove `91443` which follows `$$$$` and replace it with `"Tetrahydrofolic acid"`, e.g.

```bash
awk '
  replace { $0 = "Tetrahydrofolic acid"; replace = 0 } 
  /^\$\$\$\$$/ { replace = 1 }
1' compound.sdf
```

(the `1` is simply shorthand for the default operation `print`)

The variable `replace` is simply set to `1` when the next line should be replaced, and back to `0` after the replacement until the next record of `"$$$$"` is encountered.

**Example Use/Output**

With your example input in the file `compound.sdf`, you would get:

```
$ awk '
>   replace { $0 = "Tetrahydrofolic acid"; replace = 0 }
>   /^\$\$\$\$$/ { replace = 1 }
> 1' compound.sdf
$$$$
Tetrahydrofolic acid
  -OEChem-10051719083D

 55 57  0     1  0  0  0  0  0999 V2000
   -5.0661   -1.1129    2.4181 O   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    4.2383    1.9583    1.7563 O   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    7.3280    0.6119   -1.9919 O   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    5.1868    0.6987   -2.7387 O   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

Let me know if I misunderstood the question and I'm happy to help further.